# Adding nested lists to shared dict in Multiprocessing Pool and saving to JSON after the context

Tags: python, json, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to run a process in multiprocesses Pool as:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from multiprocessing import Manager

manager = Manager()
lock = manager.Lock()
data_dict = manager.dict({data_subset: {}})
with Pool(processes=cpu_count()-2) as p:
        with tqdm(total=len(paths)) as pbar:
            for v in p.imap_unordered(
                partial(extract_video, root_dir=opt.data_path, dataset=dataset, output_path=opt.output_path, data_dict=data_dict, data_subset=data_subset),
                paths
            ):
                pbar.update()

print(data_dict.copy())
# Save the data_dict to a JSON file
with open(os.path.join(opt.output_path, "data_dict.json"), 'w') as json_file:
   print('writing to json')
   json.dump(data_dict.copy(), json_file)
```

And here is the extract_video function:

```
def extract_video(video, root_dir, dataset, output_path, data_dict, data_subset):
    try:
       # some code to create image crops and other variables
       # ....
       for j, crop in enumerate(crops):
          image_path = os.path.join(output_path, id, "{}_{}.png".format(i, j))
          cv2.imwrite(image_path, crop)

          # Update data_dict
          label = 0  # Assuming label is 0, you can modify this based on your logic

          # Tried without lock as well
          with lock:
             if id not in data_dict[data_subset]:                    
                 data_dict[data_subset][id] = {'label': label, 'list': []} # tried manager.list() as well 
             data_dict[data_subset][id]['list'] += [image_path]  # tried append method on list as well
             # data_dict[data_subset][id] = {'label': label, 'list': [image_path]}  # Tried this by adding image_path directly to the list as well
        print(data_dict)
     except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
```

Now the problem is all code in Pool context works fine if I comment the lines adding nested objects to data_dict. But when I uncomment those lines, got some exceptions. I tried debugging the code snippets with some dummy dict and list as discussed in [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue36119) thread but no success.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine `d` is a managed dictionary created with:

```py
inner_dict_key = 'nested_dict'

...
with Manager() as manager:
    d = manager.dict({inner_dict_key: {}})
```

`d` is actually a proxy to the actual dictionary that exists in a process that is created when `Manager()` is executed. Now consider:

```py
d[inner_dict_key]['x'] = 1
```

This is equivalent to:

```py
inner_dict = d[inner_dict_key]
inner_dict['x'] = 1
```

A call, `d[inner_dict_key]` is made on the proxy which then marshals the method call and arguments and sends them to the manager's process for execution on the actual dictionary. What is returned back to the caller as `inner_dict` is the nested dictionary. But this nested dictionary is a copy of the one that exists in the manager's process. That is, `inner_dict` resides in the current process's memory. Thus the assignment `inner_dict['x'] = 1` is only updating the local copy and you see what you see.

If however, you had:

```py
inner_dict = d[inner_dict_key]
inner_dict['x'] = 1
d[inner_dict_key] = inner_dict
```

Now you are updating the copy that resides in the manager's process (the sharable dictionary) with a complete replacement of the nested dictionary. This could be expensive. But worse than that, consider the following complete program:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
from functools import partial
import time

inner_dict_key = 'nested_dict'

def worker(d, new_key, new_value):
    inner_dict = d[inner_dict_key]
    inner_dict[new_key] = new_value
    # Give a second pool process a chance to process a task:
    time.sleep(1)
    d[inner_dict_key] = inner_dict

def main():
    with Manager() as manager, Pool() as pool:
        d = manager.dict({inner_dict_key: {}})
        pool.starmap(partial(worker, d), (('x', 1), ('y', 2)))
        print(d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
{'nested_dict': {'y': 2}}
```

Only one key in the nested dictionary has been added because of the race condition. This is identical to having two processes execute `x.value += 1` where `x` is a shared `multiprocessing.Value` instance. The problem for both of these cases is that fetching the nested dictionary, updating it and storing it back out is not an atomic operation. Locking is required:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, Lock
from functools import partial
import time

inner_dict_key = 'nested_dict'

def init_pool_processes(the_lock):
    global lock

    lock = the_lock

def worker(d, new_key, new_value):
    with lock:
        inner_dict = d[inner_dict_key]
        inner_dict[new_key] = new_value
        # Give a second pool process a chance to process a task:
        time.sleep(1)
        d[inner_dict_key] = inner_dict

def main():
    with Manager() as manager, \
    Pool(initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(Lock(),)) as pool:
        d = manager.dict({inner_dict_key: {}})
        pool.starmap(partial(worker, d), (('x', 1), ('y', 2)))
        print(d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
{'nested_dict': {'x': 1, 'y': 2}}
```

The alternative is to make the nested dictionary a managed dictionary also:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
from functools import partial

inner_dict_key = 'nested_dict'

def worker(d, new_key, new_value):
    # There is no longer a race condition:
    d[inner_dict_key][new_key] = new_value

def main():
    with Manager() as manager, Pool() as pool:
        inner_dict = manager.dict()
        d = manager.dict({inner_dict_key: inner_dict})
        pool.starmap(partial(worker, d), (('x', 1), ('y', 2)))
        d_copy = d.copy()
        d_copy[inner_dict_key] = inner_dict.copy()
        print(d_copy)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
{'nested_dict': {'x': 1, 'y': 2}}
```

But now each update to the nested dictionary requires two proxy calls.

**Pick your poison.**